# If row contains any value then add one to counter cell

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, filter, count, sum

I have two main response options in a survey question: A and B, and a handful of secondary options: D, E, F.

In my data export I'll have five columns. In a separate sheet I am using COUNTIFS to get totals, but am stumped as to the best way to deal with the secondary options. Essentially, if columns D, E and F contain ANY value I would like to add +1 to a counter cell. If columns D, E and F ALL contain values I still only want this to count as one (think of it like those three comprise the "other" category and don't need to be SUMMED as individual parts).

Comment: do you want the result in each row individually or do you want a sum of all the rows that meet this criteria?

Comment: And BTW Excel will have different answer the Google-Sheets, so please let us know which you prefer.

Comment: Can you provide some sample input and the desired output in order to visually clarify this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF((D2:D<>"")+(E2:E<>"")+(F2:F<>""), 1, 0))
```

[image]

and then just sum it to get count like:

```
=SUM(INDEX(IF((D2:D<>"")+(E2:E<>"")+(F2:F<>""), 1, 0)))
```

Comment: brilliant! this is absolutely a step in the right direction. would i also be able to add qualifiers to this formula? e.g., if respondent A lives in Brazil and is a "Complete" then run SUM(INDEX...)?

Comment: @artobinvelez sure, can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: @artobinvelez see your sheet

Comment: getting close(?), but for instance brazil should has four total completes (two males, one female, and one nonbinary), but the nonbinary column is showing four... no need to take it any further, you've already helped a lot! i can take it from here, much appreciated.